# Add a separate site to discuss posts in a more relaxed manner

Tags: feature-request, community

StackExchange / Stack Overflow were built on the premise that serving the developer community at large would lead to a better, smarter Internet but in my opinion the path that you have chose to reach that goal is a terribly slow one.

The Stack communities are full of great knowledgeable answers. To make the Internet better and smarter it’s going to take more than just answers. It’s going to take understanding and comprehension of those answers. The Internet is full of young and old minds yearning to comprehend. Isn’t discussion part of learning? How do people discuss some of the answers they find on the Stack sites? Isn’t discussion contributing?

**My feature request is to expand your website to a sister website called discussion.stackexchange.com, a place to discuss posts found on Stack sites in a more relaxed manner.  By adding “Discuss this post on discussion.stackexchange” to the end of every thread** like this mock up image:

[image]

You have the site where you talk about unicorns, and the meta site where you talk about the site where you talk about unicorns. What is needed is a place where the common user can talk about the knowledge represented on unicorns.

Currently, there are two main option to "discuss" a post: the chat and comments.

The chat, while more open to discussion, requires 20 reputation points to take part in. Adding comments on the question itself, if it's not your question, would instead take 50 reputation points, and that is not even considering that comments aren't meant for extended discussion in the first place. The spur-of-the-moment users will never reach that because they don’t strive to gain a reputation on the site. The site is just there for them as a means to comprehension, nothing more.

What is my definition of the spur-of-the-moment user? The spur-of-the-moment user is a general person just that is here to find comprehension to a question, someone that is busy doing their own project but needed understanding on some topic. They are not here to gain reputation and probably won't interact a lot with votes or by posting new content. How can someone gain reputation on a subject they are just learning? Especially if they are in competition with other more qualified users.

This community is the place  for the discussion of this knowledge, since this is where the knowledge is located, not Quora or reddit.  You don't have to participate in it if you don't want to. Lots of people will participate because they want others to learn.

There is entire market of people that will participate. The experts don't have to moderate the forum. Forums themselves attract the type of people that love to moderate them. The experts aren't required to participate but they will.

As a side notice, I would like to point out that  comments are still one of the most abused feature here, often being used as a way to discuss over a post in a more "forum like" way.

> Honestly, comments are the single most abused feature of Stack
>   Exchange. However, they are also a very important part of stack
>   exchange.
>   [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186954/allow-anyone-to-comment-but-hide-low-rep-users-comments-until-reviewed)

I think that people are heavily abusing your comment feature to try to have a voice. They will continue to abuse it if you ignore them, but give them an outlet to speak and you will resolve one of your huge problems. The abuse will drop drastically and you can continue doing the others things you love, with much less hindrance.

For those that feel this request is unclear I'll break it down for you.

"My feature request is" that statement means that following it will be some words that state my request

"to expand your website to a sister website called discussion.stackexchange.com" means start a new web site that is called discussion.stackexchange.com

"a place to discuss posts found on Stack sites in a more relaxed manner" This web site will be a place where posts can be discussed in an atmosphere not as militarized as this site.

"By adding “Discuss this post on discussion.stackexchange” to the end of every thread" I think this sentence is very self-explanatory if you look at the mockup picture.

Comment: [Do Trilogy sites need "a third place"?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/), [Web-based IRC for the Trilogy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48249)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166860/what-can-i-do-if-i-want-to-further-discuss-a-specific-answer-to-a-question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222938/creating-and-linking-chat-rooms-to-questions

Comment: For what purpose do I, expert of unicorns, need to talk with common users?

Comment: Why are you emphasizing "common"?

Comment: Please don't be so arrogant it impairs the learning of knowledge. Power tends to corrupt and absolute power corrupts absolutely. You have forgotten the site was not built for you, you are the expert. **The site was built on the premise that serving the developer community at large would lead to a better, smarter Internet.** How is that supposed to happen if the common user can not freely discuss question and answers.

Comment: I thought we already have quora and reddit for the freely discussion so that we can here focus on the real deal?

Comment: As I stated in my request. That is a slow way to reach the result the site was based on. Why force uses to go somewhere away from the focal point of the real deal. The experts are located here, on this site. How are users supposed to learn, comprehend and possibly expand their knowledge to something they weren't even thinking about if they are not talking to the experts. My request wouldnt dilute this site it's separate but in the same community.

Comment: I'm not going to spend my valuable free time on *discussing* unicorns with a group of **common** users that is even more likely to be never interested in giving anything back to this community. Maybe when all new incoming questions about unicorns are high quality, well researched, clear and useful I might consider to discuss things *freely*. But I don't see that happen within another 6 to 8 years.

Comment: This site is not for discussions. And shouldn't be. There is a place for everything and this is not the place for discussions. (Unless you count chat, that *is* the place for discussions)

Comment: Re your edit asking people not to downvote, please read [What is meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Voting on meta is different, "voting indicates agreement or disagreement". You can't get around that just by telling people not to.

Comment: We already have chat but you don't say why this is a duplicate of what chat already does. You also do not define what a "common" user is. If that means yet another site were there is no barrier to quality control, then perhaps Stack Exchange is not the right place for you

Comment: Downvotes also mean this post is sloppy, uninformed, ill-researched, duplicating existing features

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120359/discussing-an-answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139282/i-dont-understand http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145510/answers-are-too-complicated

Comment: This started off as such a reasonable idea; I really didn't expect an anti-elitist rant in the very first comment. "You have forgotten the site was not built for you, you are the expert" Some food for thought on this assertion, by the founder: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118764/159251 and by a former top user: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121333/159251

Comment: _"quality answers to quality questions" should be the tagline of Stack Exchange."_

**My request was not to change the way SE does things it would be a separate site for discussion**

Comment: _"We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A; system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answers. If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it. Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?"_

**Again request was not to change the way SE does things it would be a separate site for disscussion**

Comment: _"Thus, if you want to come on our "campus" and learn with your fellow students, we expect users to be armed with the basics and fundamentals of the field. Users who fail to meet the absolute minimum standards of a practicing professional, whatever field that happens to be (think FizzBuzz for programmers), should be helpfully directed to other resources where they can learn these things before coming back."_

**Why can't discussion.stackexchange.com be that place?**

Comment: _"The idea that you have all these experts waiting in the wings to do stuff is an illusion in my experience. There's really just a bunch of amateurs muddling along trying to do things together. The people that are truly experts are too busy to even help, right? And if the experts are too busy to help, what difference does it really make if there are experts at all. Because the whole point of this endeavor is helping other developers, and whether you're an expert or not, if you have no time to help, you're not really contributing to the solution."_

**Is discussion not contributing?**

Comment: Hey look! A new user who has no idea how things work around here suggesting how things should work!

Comment: @20GT Who or what are you quoting?

Comment: Those appear to be quoting the blog post about how you can't spoon-feed everyone just because they demand to have their hand held every step of the way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we have a subjective version of every Stack Exchange site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/should-we-have-a-subjective-version-of-every-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Comment: Sorry, this question may have a lot of dupes, may be something most people will disagree on but still seem pretty clear in its new form (btw, topic creator, I have edited it a little to remove some part that felt a little more "ranting" than "discussing" so that people won't be distracted by them) so I am voting to reopen. May still be appropiate to close it as a dupe if one fitting target is found.

Comment: @gnat, Rory Alsop,  possibly 6 years ago, but your problem still exists today.

Comment: @HDE 226868, random, sorry I was quoting 
blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-san‌nd 
meta.stackexchange.com/a/118764/159251 
meta.stackexchange.com/a/121333/159251 

gnat, that was a site where questions that were too subjective / broad for Stack Overflow would find a new home. Still it was for questions, not discussion, not a forum.

Comment: @Josh Caswell sorry it was a rash knee jerk reaction to Rene’s comment
“For what purpose do I, expert of unicorns, need to talk with common users?”

Cai I said community not site 

random “If that means yet another site were there is no barrier to quality control” It will need quality control it will just be a forum about the answers not based on the answer model.

Comment: Look back and see how many comments refer to “this site” as if I’m asking to change the answer type model or interfere with this site. That's not what this request is. Your community and this site model are two different things entirely. You have probably over 98 sites, have any of them affected this site adversely?

I’ll admit it, I’m a  spur-of-the-moment user. If the site was about cleaning or janitorial procedures I’d have something to contribute, because I already know that field. I’m 48 I’m learning programming to write a particular program and that will be about it.

Comment: You as the true caretakers of this site can choose to ignore your comment problem for another 6 years or kill two birds with one stone. Fix your commenting problem and create a nurturing place to learn in the process. 

That's about all the time all have to spend on this topic. Take care.

Comment: Take away the reputation gatekeeper of chat and how is that not what this request is asking for? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97859/can-users-with-less-reputation-be-allowed-to-chat http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141873/new-users-without-souls http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141269/new-users-are-hairless http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99491/newbie-oncoming-storm

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that creating another site for discussions is a good idea. In my opinion [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) is a good place for discussions.

Comment: Take it to chat, it requires 20 reputation points. The common user will never reach that because they don’t strive to gain a reputation on the site. The site is just there for them as a means to comprehension nothing more.

Comment: @20GT Are you kidding? 20 reputation points is ridiculously small amount. You can earn that by getting two upvotes on your answers.

Comment: @Gothdo or 10 approved suggested-edits, those are even easier ...

Comment: The common user is not answering questions or suggested-edits they are un-knowledgeable users. They are the common user like myself that is just looking for knowledge.

Comment: @20GT As I wrote in my answer, over one million people on Stack Overflow have managed to get chat privileges, and I'm betting that many, many more have earned *some* rep. I really dispute your claims.

Comment: _one million people_  compared to 6,205,952 users that's roughly 1 to 6 which does not make the _chat_ user's common.

Comment: @20GT Did you read my answer? I'm willing to bet that the others are folks who came, posted once, and left. If they stayed, they could easily earn rep. It's not that they couldn't, it's that they chose not to.

Answer (score 6):

Your suggestion relies on the premise that "common users" will not

1. Earn the 20 rep needed to use chat.
2. Earn the 50 rep needed to comment on posts.

I dispute this. Stack Overflow currently has over 160,000 pages of users. Over [*30,000*](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=30000&tab=reputation&filter=all) of those pages contain users with at least 20 reputation points. Yes, that's less than 20% of all users. But I'm going to bet that the remaining 130,000 pages consist of people who have asked or answered maybe one or two questions, at most, and gotten a vote or two. If they post more - or edit, for instance - they can easily hit 20 rep, and then 50 rep.

At 36 users per page, that's over one **million** users who have managed to gain chat privileges - on Stack Overflow alone! I can *guarantee* you that not all of those users are "experts", and I can also guarantee you that most of those users are what you might call "common users". If they can do it with a little bit of effort, there's no reason why someone else shouldn't be able to.

Chat exists for a reason, and it's perfectly easy to get the rep needed to get there. Everyone starts from exactly 1 rep. Nobody goes in with an advantage - and the same applies for all Stack Exchange sites.

Ask, answer, edit, and you can get the discussion you want.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** Stack Exchange doesn't need a site for discussions about the answers (or questions).

> To make the Internet better and smarter it’s going to take more than just answers. It’s going to take understanding and comprehension of those answers.

That is true. We expect visitors to invest their time to understand and comprehend both the problem they have in their own context and how any of the answers found fit in, relate to or don't apply to their situation. Visitors who don't understand or comprehend an proposed solution have a different issue: they need to do more research or verify if they understand their own context correctly.

> The Internet is full of young and old minds yearning to comprehend. Isn’t discussion part of learning? How do people discuss some of the answers they find on the stack web sites?

Yes, discussion can be a great part of learning. I have to assume you expect an *discussion* to be needed because either an answer or question you found on a Stack Exchange is unclear. There is no problem to ask a *new* question where you reference other questions or answers, explain how you think it is relevant to your specific case and then ask your new and unique question. By doing that you help extending the knowledge gathered here. Specially if you're inexperienced it can be extremely helpful to have questions that help those that have the answers to be precise and clear in their answers.

> It is to expand your website to a sister website called discussion.stackexchange.com, a place to discuss posts found on Stack Exchange in a more relaxed manner.

Honestly, that model is not a good fit to gather and curate valuable knowledge that is useful for future visitors. Such sites, some call them forums, are more geared towards the needs of individuals. Although extremely useful for those that need help, not very much for future visitors and those future visitors is were we should aim for.

> You expect more from the common user, forcing them to earn reputation to chat, but you don't feel obliged to discuss your knowledge freely. Don't you desire people to learn?

We're not forcing any one. We cater for all who have enough on Google hits or the Stack's own search engine. Those who are really invested do make those few suggested edits, or ask those great question, that will open up their ability to participate in and with the community. And sure, everybody is allowed to learn but that doesn't mean that the volunteers on this site should be spoon-feeding, teach, coach, educate those who are too lazy to give learning a serious try themselves. You learn at the edges of your knowledge. We are not going to explore where your edges are, that is up to you, by asking a decent question. From there we'll share what we know to the best of our abilities.

> The common user is not answering questions or suggested-edits they are un-knowledgeable users. They are the common user like myself that is just looking for knowledge.

If you're just looking for knowledge you have found the right kind of sites. There is enormous amount of value hidden in all those posts and tag-wikis and documentation on Stack Overflow. If you want to transit from un-knowledgeable to noob you have to do the effort. Realizing something you've found is unclear is the first step. Running up to someone demanding or expecting they explain stuff to you is simply over-asking, if not rude.

If it really matters to you I would not assume that the volunteers here are unwilling or not prepared to share. The 8 years these sites exist it's users and communities have learned a lot on how to curate knowledge and make that accessible to huge numbers of users. For one thing we are pretty sure: the forum/thread/discussion format doesn't fit the Q/A model and the majority of users that answer questions here do so because of that format. Maybe it is worth to spend some time to understand why that is and why it makes sites like Stack Overflow high ranked in Google. It might turn out that the Q/A model is fine, even or maybe specially for users that are new to a certain topic.